# Missing dependency error on useEffect for a ref?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the custom hook usePrevious. code taken from here : https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-christian-zlvht1?file=/src/App.js:0-623

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
// Usage
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count);
  const test = useRef("test");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Why is there a missing dependency error on prevCount?
    console.log(prevCount);
    // but not test.current one?
    console.log(test.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}
      </h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
// Hook
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}
```

Why is the value that I used the usePrevious on considered a useEffect dependency? I thought that ref's aren't considered dependencies. I get the latest usePrevious value no matter what, so what is the point of this warning? Is it safe to ignore?

My main app messes up if I put the usePrevious value as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there a missing dependency error on prevCount?

Because `prevCount` is the value that `usePrevious` hook returns.

> I thought that ref's aren't considered dependencies.

And you are right, `useEffect` in `usePrevious` will be called **only** when `value` changes. It will not be called if `ref` changes.

> Is it safe to ignore?

Definitely not. If you do, your `useEffect` in `App` will not listen to `prevCount` updates.

Comment: > "Definitely not. If you do, your useEffect in App will not listen to prevCount updates."

I edited the codesandbox to show this is not true. Have a look at line 16 and 17. Also, as you can see, if you do put the prevCount as a dependency, then it starts running the effect hook twice.

Comment: @user349557 but the first `useEffect` (without `prevCount` as dependency) does not even fire.

Comment: I don't want it to fire if prevCount changes. It's a ref, it doesn't matter if it changes either, it will always be the same value regardless of dependencies, right? Is it safe to ignore this error?

Comment: Here is another sandbox without the custom hook, but this one doesn't give me a warning. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-roentgen-12ti3v?file=/src/App.js